# in my wordpress blog when click on pagination link it redirect to wrong url

Tags: wordpress

i already tried 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/clicking-on-page-2-redirects-to-the-home-page

here is my url of pagination which is correct
http://studycopter.com/feed/page/2/

but when i click on link then it redirect to
http://studycopter.com/page/2/

i check every things 
like 
.htaccess file
permalink
site url 
base url
also deactivate all plugins

but didn't resolve the issue

Please Help me!

Comment: can you paste your code which regenerates your pagination. Do you use wp query on that page? etc etc..

Comment: @Christophvh  i used default query of page generation didn't change in code i install wordpress on /blog folder initially and after some time i changed my site url /blog to /feed     the above mention problem occurs after changing instalation folder of my wordpress bolg

Comment: after changing your folder name, change the first 2 values in your options table of your database to the correct value & go to settings -> permalinks and save those again to reset your links.

Comment: Thanks @Christophvh ... but i already do these steps

Comment: now it is resolve by changing /wp-includes/canonical.php the problem occurs due to feed keyword which is in url    // paging and feeds
by changing  while ( preg_match( "#/$wp_rewrite->pagination_base/?[0-9]+?(/+)?$#", $redirect['path'] ) || preg_match( '#/(comments/?)?(rss|rdf|atom|rss2)(/+)?$#', $redirect['path'] ) || preg_match( "#/{$wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base}-[0-9]+(/+)?$#", $redirect['path'] ) ) { $redirect['path'] = preg_replace('#/(comments/?)?(rss2?|rdf|atom)(/+|$)#', '/', $redirect['path']); // strip off feed endings}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem Resolved

the problem occurs due to feed keyworrd
by changing /wp-includes/canonical.php

//before the code is

```
// paging and feeds
if ( get_query_var('paged') || is_feed() || get_query_var('cpage') ) {
    while ( preg_match( "#/$wp_rewrite->pagination_base/?[0-9]+?(/+)?$#", $redirect['path'] ) || preg_match( '#/(comments/?)?(feed/rss|rdf|atom|rss2)(/+)?$#', $redirect['path'] ) || preg_match( "#/{$wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base}-[0-9]+(/+)?$#", $redirect['path'] ) ) {
        // Strip off paging and feed
        $redirect['path'] = preg_replace("#/$wp_rewrite->pagination_base/?[0-9]+?(/+)?$#", '/', $redirect['path']); // strip off any existing paging
        $redirect['path'] = preg_replace('#/(comments/?)?(feed/rss2?|rdf|atom)(/+|$)#', '/', $redirect['path']); // strip off feed endings
        $redirect['path'] = preg_replace("#/{$wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base}-[0-9]+?(/+)?$#", '/', $redirect['path']); // strip off any existing comment paging
    }

    //more code

}
```

//after removing feed

```
// paging and feeds
if ( get_query_var('paged') || is_feed() || get_query_var('cpage') ) {
    while ( preg_match( "#/$wp_rewrite->pagination_base/?[0-9]+?(/+)?$#", $redirect['path'] ) || preg_match( '#/(comments/?)?(rss|rdf|atom|rss2)(/+)?$#', $redirect['path'] ) || preg_match( "#/{$wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base}-[0-9]+(/+)?$#", $redirect['path'] ) ) {
        // Strip off paging and feed
        $redirect['path'] = preg_replace("#/$wp_rewrite->pagination_base/?[0-9]+?(/+)?$#", '/', $redirect['path']); // strip off any existing paging
        $redirect['path'] = preg_replace('#/(comments/?)?(rss2?|rdf|atom)(/+|$)#', '/', $redirect['path']); // strip off feed endings
        $redirect['path'] = preg_replace("#/{$wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base}-[0-9]+?(/+)?$#", '/', $redirect['path']); // strip off any existing comment paging
    }

    //more code

}
```